# How do I kill the goblins to get out of Gringott's?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

In *LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7*, Year 7 Part 2 "The Thief’s Downfall", when Harry, Ron, & Hermione are on the Dragon trying to get out of Gringotts, how do you kill the 5 Goblins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to switch to Hermione, she can throw some spells at the goblins.

Answer (score 1):

Use Harry to point the dragon towards the goblins then switch to Hermione and she can cast a targeted spell.

Answer (score -1):

The long version is to breathe fire for ages until they all eventually die.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming SE lolza!  Are you absolutely certain that you can use the dragon's breath weapon to defeat the goblins in the top area?  I spent a long time replaying that part of the game tonight and I was unable to do anything to the goblins until I switched to the second character as per the other answers.